# How can i log when getText() doesn't find a translation and uses the given string instead?

Tags: php, logging, gettext

i need to log any calls to gettext(), which use the fallback case (the given string) because there was no translation found. Is there a way to log that information?

If that makes a difference: I use _('stringToBeTranlated'); and not gettext('...').

Comment: Could you just compare before and after? That would work with gettext().

Comment: In this special case i work on, there are no placeholders, so i cant differ, if there is an entry in the .po file which is just set to the string itself as default, or if getText used fallback for "nothing found".